# last opened tab not stored in localstorage when tabs loaded using ng-repeat

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, tabs

using ng-repeat to load bootstrap tabs dynamically

```
    <li ng-class="{'active': $index==0}" ng-repeat="s in subMenu | orderBy:'id'"><a ng-show="s.accessible==true" data-toggle="tab" data-target="{{s.dataTarget}}">{{s.label}}</a></li>
```

Its working fine but failing to store the last opened tab. On refresh first tab is shown.I am using the following to store last opened tab.

```
     $(function() { 
            $('a[data-toggle="tab"]').on('shown.bs.tab', function (e) {
            // save the latest tab
                localStorage.setItem('lastTab', $(this).attr('data-target'));
            });

            // go to the latest tab, if it exists:
            var lastTab = localStorage.getItem('lastTab');
            if (lastTab) {
                $('[data-target="' + lastTab + '"]').tab('show');
            }
        });
```

If tabs are loaded statically then the above code works fine. How to modify it for dynamic load ?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Get rid of bootstrap.js completely and use angular-ui-bootstrap

Comment: is there no workaround possible around present code